# How to use FConvEncoder as word embedding in fairseq?

Tags: nlp, word-embedding, fairseq

I want to use pretrained GLoVe in FConvEncoder and then by using something like FConvEncoder.encoder(sentence) (e.g. sentence = "This is a good sentence") turn my sentence into an 2D array with a fixed-length embedding dimension. something like (1, 300)
Is it possible to do this with FConvEncoder? If not can you suggest me a pretrained LSTM/CNN encoder that can transform my sentence into a fixed-length dimension of numbers?